# Session ID not the same in my Java EE application

Tags: java, session, authentication, servlets

I've written a application with a custom login system. And then written my own security filter for it which sets the area that can be accessed. Yet I always get redirected to the login page and then to the index page with is the logged in home page. I have discovered that the session ID is different from when I login to when I try to use something that is restricted. Here is my code:

```
public class securtityFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            // if there is no userBean, then they have not gone through
            // the login, so kick them to the login page
            if(null==req.getSession().getAttribute("username"))
            {
                ((HttpServletResponse)servletResponse).sendRedirect("../Login.jsp");
                System.out.println("Redirected - No session");

            }
                    // otherwise, let them go to the page/resource they want
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                System.out.println("Gone through Filter");

              //  System.out.println("In Filter Servlet: "+ req.getSession().getId());

            }

public void destroy() {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.                   
}
}
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
  <filter>
     <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>filters.securtityFilter</filter-class>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/add/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you sure the login page is setting the username attribute?

Comment: Yes in the login servlet:  
    while(rs.next())
                {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    String  tmp = rs.getString(1);
                    System.out.println(tmp);
                    session.setAttribute("username",tmp);
                    /*role = rs.getInt("level");
                    session.setAttribute("role",role);*/
                    count++;    
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login servlet you have

```
while (rs.next())
{
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
  String tmp = rs.getString(1);
  System.out.println(tmp);
  session.setAttribute("username", tmp); 
  count++;
 }
```

So if you have no username attribute in your session, it is because this code block is not being executed. I assume that you are looping through the results of a database query, so check whether the actual query that you are executing returns any results.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(null==req.getSession().getAttribute("username"))
```

to

```
HttpSession ses = req.getSession(false); // null if no current
if(null == ses || 
   null == ses.getAttribute("username"))
```

so that it never creates a new session inside your filter. Let the login page create the sessions.

Comment: This is the error that now pops up:
25-Jul-2009 22:46:30 org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl internalGetPageContext
SEVERE: Exception initializing page context
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Comment: Add return statements immediately after your redirects. And make sure you are not doing anything with the HttpResponse in your filters chain

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry i am new to J2EE.

Comment: Whereever you have sendRedirect() calls just add a return after them. It is complaining because something is being written to the HttpResponse besides the redirect you wanted.

Comment: OK Thanks for that yet it didn't work im still getting redirected to the login page.